# Is there any background Http request retry mechanism in Scala Play Framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, akka

I have 2 Scala + Play Framework applications that communicate with HTTP requests.

**Issue scenario:**

One app lets say A is getting request from outside (for example Postman) and everything it's doing just redirecting request to app B. Code of controller:

```
SecuredAction.async(parse.json[JsObject]) { implicit request =>
  implicit val user: User = request.identity
 
  withMetrics {
    appBclient.doCalculations(request.body, <some query params>)
  } toResult
}
```

For one who wondering what is withMetrics:

```
  protected def withMetrics(res: => Future[JsObject]): Future[JsObject] = {
   val timer = txScoreTimer.start()
   res.transform(
     { json => json ++ Json.obj("_api" -> Json.obj( "processingTimeSeconds" -> 
       timer.observe)) },
     { e: Throwable =>
       val tookSeconds = timer.observe
       e match {
      case g: GeneralException => g.copy(processingTimeSeconds = Some(tookSeconds))
      case _ => e
    }
  }
)
```

}

App B calculate something really long time so app A gets timeout exception after 120 sec:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to host after 120000 ms
at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
at play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:48)
at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:663)
at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:738)
at play.shaded.ahc.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:466)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

After that app B receive this exact request again after some time after failing, but there is no logic for retries in my code as I can see.

So my question is there anything that could cause this issue, maybe some env variable for application or Play Framework, I really confused with this one.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Never sees anything like that even though I work with Play apps daily.

Comment: Is there any network proxy between the two apps? Load balancer? What do the access logs of service B say in terms of timing, headers..? Did you use something like Wireshark to confirm the call comes from service A?

Comment: This happens on company environment so I'm not able to use wireshark. All I know this apps working on same mesos + marathon environments, I'm not really familiar with this technologies, all I can say for sure there is only one instance of each app running. Both requests received by app B is identical, I logged it and it has absolutely the same data (body, headers, host, remoteHost etc)

Comment: Can you share the code of serviceBClient?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I would comment, but I don't have the points on StackOverflow yet to do so.

I'm not sure if this is applicable, and I definitely see this being a bit of a hassle, but have you thought creating a JobScheduler system? The call to AppA will add register a new async function to AppB as a new job with a pending status, and return the jobId. The async function will call AppB but also associate the response to the jobId, update the job status. Then have a new polling endpoint to AppA with the jobId.

Just a thought. Cheers.